# Semantic UI Step usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I am trying to use Semantic UI Step (https://semantic-ui.com/elements/step.html) in my app, but can't figure out how to use it.

I understand the UI aspect of it, but can't figure out the following:

1. How can I change the `<a class="active step">` whenever a user clicks on a step, and make other steps inactive?
2. How do I display different content in `<div class="ui attached segment">` everytime a step is clicked?
3. How do I disable other steps while something is being processed in one of the steps?

I am new to semantic and web in general. I was thinking to use jQuery to get these components and update everything through that, but I am not sure if that's a good approach?

Can someone please suggest something with a code snippet? Thank you for your help!

This is the UI part of it from Semantic UI.

```
<div class="ui three top attached steps">
  <a class="step">
    <i class="truck icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Shipping</div>
      <div class="description">Choose your shipping options</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="active step">
    <i class="payment icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Billing</div>
      <div class="description">Enter billing information</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="disabled step">
    <i class="info icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Confirm Order</div>
      <div class="description">Verify order details</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="ui attached segment">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: [jQuery .click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) [jQuery .toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), these may be of use, also note `$('a .active')` will select active anchor tags

Comment: Using toggleClass I can toggle class of only one step, how do I control other steps? Also, I don't want to select active anchor tags, I want to make them active, disabled etc.

Comment: sorry, I was trying to just throw in something that would be useful for part of the problem, not the whole. As far as changing the content looking at the [segment](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/segment.html) docs, it looks like you could simply have however many segments as your steps and hide/show them along with activating / deactivating / disabling the steps. The jQuery i mentioned above was kinda meant to be a reminder that you can select generically and edit multiple at a time (but it was poorly executed)

Comment: okay, no problem! Thanks for your help, I'll look in to segments

Answer (score 0):

If you and an id to each step like stepShip, stepBill and stepConfirm

```
<a id="stepShip" class="step">
```

A function like this

```
var setStep = function(id){
    $('#'+id).addClass('active').nextAll().addClass('disabled').removeClass('active');
};
```

Can then be called at start up like this

```
setStep("stepConfirm");
```

or attached to the steps like this

```
$('.step').click(function(){setStep($(this).attr('id'));})
```